# How to Get Apps to Show Full Screen on Chromebook?

Tags: android, fullscreen, chromebook

I've been making Android apps for a long time and can get them to open in full screen mode on every device except Chromebook. No matter what I do, they only open about half screen and a user has to click the "maximize" button to get them to open further.

Here is the code I use to try to get the apps full screen:

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

in the relevant `style` in `themes.xml`

as well as

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` method.

I've also tried putting

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

in the `application` block of `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Is there something else I can do to get the apps to open full screen on Chromebook?

(I'm using HP Chromebook x360, if that helps)

Comment: I don't have a chromebook, so cannot test. But did you try hiding system bars? https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/immersive#java

Comment: Have you seen/tried: https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/window-management#initial_launch_size

Comment: @MorrisonChang That works! Could you please add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is a section of the Android documentation for using Android on ChromeOS which makes reference to [Window Management - Launch Size](https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/window-management#initial_launch_size) which seems appropriate.

Quoting from the documentation:

> - Use a launch size only in desktop environments. This helps the window manager to give you the proper bounds and orientation. To indicate a preferences when used in desktop mode, add the following meta tags inside the <activity>:

```
<meta-data android:name="WindowManagerPreference:FreeformWindowSize"
       android:value="[phone|tablet|maximize]" />
<meta-data android:name="WindowManagerPreference:FreeformWindowOrientation"
       android:value="[portrait|landscape]" />
```

> - Use static launch bounds. Use  inside the manifest entry of your activity to specify a "fixed" starting size. See this example:

```
<layout android:defaultHeight="500dp"
        android:defaultWidth="600dp"
        android:gravity="top|end"
        android:minHeight="450dp"
        android:minWidth="300dp" />
```

> - Use dynamic launch bounds. An activity can create and use `ActivityOptions.setLaunchBounds(Rect)` when creating a new activity. By specifying an empty rectangle, your app can be maximized.

> **Note: These options work only if the activity started is a root activity. You can also do this using a springboard activity to clear the activity stack in the task with a new start.**

Comment: The first bullet point worked for me. I also had to make sure to put it in every activity, not the application, code in the manifest.